# Initialize camera option along with gallery in dialog box

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, dialog

i'm using intents to initialize the following actions
[image]

now besides this gallery option i want camera option too, i tried the following code but didn't work

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent();
            cameraIntent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
             cameraIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),0);


        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

it shows the gallery option but not camera..
Help me to figure out this issue....

**EDITED:**

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cameraa:
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Save Project!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intents = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "Pic.jpg");
                intents.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                startActivityForResult(intents, 1);

                break;

            case R.id.gallery:
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Take Snapshot!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // ////This is gallery intent
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: @Hidde thanks for your suggestions, i accept the ans when they are useful for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this code might be helpful to you,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: this code is perfect for initializing the camera activity only, i think you didn't get my question, i want camera+gallery option in that dialogbox,

Comment: ohk.... i thought for camera only welll you can get open gallery also but how to combine both i dont have idea :( if you want gallery's code i can help you

Comment: i did that using menu inflater, that was not the required thing but task is acheived